# does the Intel UHD Graphics Support OpenGL 2.1?

Tags: opengl

I need to know if the Intel UHD Graphics supports OpenGL 2.1 because I need it to run the game "RFLEX".

Answer (score 2):

Knowing precisely what CPU you have would be more certain, but UHD tends to refer to anything [Kaby Lake refresh onwards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Graphics_Technology#Kaby_Lake_Refresh_/_Amber_Lake_/_Coffee_Lake_/_Coffee_Lake_Refresh_/_Whiskey_Lake_/_Comet_Lake), so 2017.

That will certainly be Open GL 2.1 capable, probably right up to 4.6. Open GL 2.1 was pretty much the standard from 2005 or so. Anything made since then ought to support it.

*From comments*
The [Esri OpenGL Extensions Viewer](https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000011375) will allow you to check for yourself which version of Open GL your GPU supports.

Comment: https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005524/graphics.html shows all supported API's for intel graphics controllers, including UHD obv. You are correct, it supports opengl upto 4.6

Comment: Seems that a number of places suggest [OpenGL Extensions Viewer](https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000011375) as a good tool to find out exactly what the GPU supports. Could be a good addition to the answer as a more definitive way to know.